# Last (I think and hope) problems configuring SSL certificate with Apache and VirtualHosts

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl, http, https

Finally I set apache2 to [get a single certificate for all subdomains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4595313/can-i-use-a-single-sslcertificatefile-for-all-my-virtualhosts-instead-of-creating).

```
[...]

# Go ahead and accept connections for these vhosts
# from non-SNI clients
SSLStrictSNIVHostCheck off


# Apache setup which will listen for and accept SSL connections on port 443.
Listen 443
# Listen for virtual host requests on all IP addresses
NameVirtualHost *:443


# Because this virtual host is defined first, it will
# be used as the default if the hostname is not received
# in the SSL handshake, e.g. if the browser doesn't support
# SNI.
<VirtualHost *:443>
  ServerName domain.localhost
  DocumentRoot "/Users/<my_user_name>/Sites/domain/public"

  <Directory "/Users/<my_user_name>/Sites/domain/public">
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
  </Directory>

  # SSL Configuration
  SSLEngine on
  ...
</VirtualHost>


<VirtualHost *:443>
  ServerName subdomain1.domain.localhost
  DocumentRoot "/Users/<my_user_name>/Sites/subdomain1/public"

  <Directory "/Users/<my_user_name>/Sites/subdomain1/public">
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
  </Directory>

  # SSL Configuration
  SSLEngine on
  ...
</VirtualHost>


<VirtualHost *:443>
  ServerName subdomain2.domain.localhost
  DocumentRoot "/Users/<my_user_name>/Sites/subdomain2/public"

  <Directory "/Users/<my_user_name>/Sites/subdomain2/public">
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
  </Directory>

  # SSL Configuration
  SSLEngine on
  ...
</VirtualHost>
```

So, for example, I can correctly access

```
https://subdomain1.domain.localhost
https://subdomain2.domain.localhost
...
```

Now, anyway, I have problems on accessing

```
http://subdomain1.domain.localhost
http://subdomain2.domain.localhost
...
```

Since I use a Mac Os, on accessing the "http: version", I get a default page "**Your website.**" (instead of a error). Why does it happen?

**EDIT**: **Partially solved** B-\

Add "somewhere" in the '**httpd.conf**' this code for all subdomains a for the domain (example for '*domain.localhost*'):

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName domain.localhost
  DocumentRoot "/Users/<my_user_name>/Sites/domain/public"

  <Directory "/Users/<my_user_name>/Sites/domain/public">
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Now when I try to access `http://subdomain1.domain.localhost` or `http://subdomain2.domain.localhost`, the browser redirect me automatically to `http://domain.localhost`. Why? How solve it?

Comment: Do you have any virtualhosts defined for VirtualHost *:80

Comment: No yet! I am trying. If you have some help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now add the part from your EDIT `<VirtualHost *:80>` for each subdomain:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName subdomain1.domain.localhost
...

<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName subdomain2.domain.localhost
...
```

Comment: I added these for all subdomains and for the domain, but now when I access http: //subdomain1.domain.localhost or http: //subdomain2.domain.localhost, the browser redirect me automatically to http: //domain.localhost. Why? How resolve it?

Comment: The trick is to add 'NameVirtualHost *: 80'! SOLVED.

Answer (score 0):

You must have a separate definition for all the http virtualhosts. So, for each https, a matching http.