# Last (I think and hope) problems configuring SSL certificate with Apache and VirtualHosts

Tags: apache-2.2, http, configuration, ssl, https

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Last (I think and hope) problems configuring SSL certificate with Apache and VirtualHosts](https://serverfault.com/questions/219218/last-i-think-and-hope-problems-configuring-ssl-certificate-with-apache-and-vir)

Finally I set apache2 to [get a single certificate for all subdomains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4595313/can-i-use-a-single-sslcertificatefile-for-all-my-virtualhosts-instead-of-creating).

```
[...]

# Go ahead and accept connections for these vhosts
# from non-SNI clients
SSLStrictSNIVHostCheck off


# Apache setup which will listen for and accept SSL connections on port 443.
Listen 443
# Listen for virtual host requests on all IP addresses
NameVirtualHost *:443


# Because this virtual host is defined first, it will
# be used as the default if the hostname is not received
# in the SSL handshake, e.g. if the browser doesn't support
# SNI.
<VirtualHost *:443>
  ServerName domain.localhost
  DocumentRoot "/Users/<my_user_name>/Sites/domain/public"

  <Directory "/Users/<my_user_name>/Sites/domain/public">
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
  </Directory>

  # SSL Configuration
  SSLEngine on
  ...
</VirtualHost>


<VirtualHost *:443>
  ServerName subdomain1.domain.localhost
  DocumentRoot "/Users/<my_user_name>/Sites/subdomain1/public"

  <Directory "/Users/<my_user_name>/Sites/subdomain1/public">
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
  </Directory>

  # SSL Configuration
  SSLEngine on
  ...
</VirtualHost>


<VirtualHost *:443>
  ServerName subdomain2.domain.localhost
  DocumentRoot "/Users/<my_user_name>/Sites/subdomain2/public"

  <Directory "/Users/<my_user_name>/Sites/subdomain2/public">
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
  </Directory>

  # SSL Configuration
  SSLEngine on
  ...
</VirtualHost>
```

So, for example, I can correctly access

```
https://subdomain1.domain.localhost
https://subdomain2.domain.localhost
...
```

Now, anyway, I have problems on accessing

```
http://subdomain1.domain.localhost
http://subdomain2.domain.localhost
...
```

Since I use a Mac Os, on accessing the "http: version", I get a default page "**Your website.**" (instead of a error). Why does it happen?

Answer (score 0):

For the http://foo you'll need other virtualhosts starting with

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
```

Do you have them?

http://www.foo.com and https://www.foo.com are distinct Virtualhosts.

You need as well to listen not only on port 443, check you have a *Listen 80* as well and the *NameVirtualHost *:80*. Well if you have the 'It works' chances are that you have theses settings but not the Virtualhosts.

You can ask apache for a complete listing of what he understand of your Virtualhosts. here I use '**apache2**', depending on your installation the apache binary could be '**httpd**' or something else.
execute :

```
apache 2 -S
```

or

```
apache2 -t -D DUMP_VHOSTS
```

Then you'll get the list of virtualhosts. You can see virtualhosts on *:80and *:443 are on different stacks.

If you think it's boring to copy-paste long Virtualhosts definitions which are quite the same on the *:80 and the *:443 Virtualhosts use **Include** instruction to share the settings which are the same between the VHs.

Comment: 'apache 2 -S' and 'apache2 -t -D DUMP_VHOSTS' don't work on my Mac OS.

Comment: I can't edit your answer, but if you had something like <VirtualHost *:80>, you can use \< to keep the tag from being eaten by SO's HTML parser.

Comment: @SilverbackNet yes, thanks, I was tired, I forgot to check the escapes.

Comment: @user502052 did you try with httpd instead of apache2 ?